# Ability to generate dynamic content in parameter choices in Scala instead of Groovy

Tags: scala, jenkins

Whenever I want dynamic content in Jenkins tasks, e.g. for filling combos in parameters, I have to use Groovy.

Groovy is a nice language, but I know more deeply Scala.

Is there a way of doing this?

Long ago, I've made [this request](https://github.com/adamretter/jenkins-scala-plugin/issues/1) to the author of the jenkins-scala-plugin.

Answer (score 0):

When way of doing this, although not optimal, because a new JVM is launched, is to create a Scala script that prints all the dynamic content.

I create an `Extended choice parameter`, and call my Scala script in this way:

```
"/home/jenkins/bin/sampleScript.scala".execute().text.tokenize('\n')
```

Contents of `sampleScript.scala`:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec scala "$0" "$@"
!#
(1 to 20).foreach(i => println("Option "+i))
```

As it can be seen, an one-line simple Groovy script, calls my Scala script.